# maven site escape html tags

Tags: maven

I am trying to create a site using the maven-site-plugin. it uses the content of the description in the about link. How do I put line breaks in the description. Right now it show everything in one line. I tried < 
 \n none of them worked

Comment: Can you show the complete contents of the file? which format do you use apt, xdoc ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Description from [maven site](http://maven.apache.org/ref/2.2.1/maven-model/maven.html#class_project) for the element `<description>`.

> A detailed description of the project, used by Maven whenever it needs
>   to describe the project, such as on the web site. While this element
>   can be specified as CDATA to enable the use of HTML tags within the
>   description, it is discouraged to allow plain text representation. If
>   you need to modify the index page of the generated web site, you are
>   able to specify your own instead of adjusting this text.

Comment: Thank you so much, stupid me, should have looked at the official docs first. Thanks again